# Real life description for (~A->A)->A

Tags: logic, intuition, propositional-logic

It can be shown that the logical preposition [ :- (~A->A)->A ] is a theorem (always true).
I want to know if anybody knows a real life description for the preposition above?
I mean an expression in computer, economics, mathematics, politics or anything that fits in that preposition.

Comment: Reminds me of Catch-22: (You don't want to be a pilot -> You are sane and should be a pilot) -> You will be a pilot

Comment: @d'alar'cop Nice. But that doesn't quite work as "You don't want to be a pilot" is not the same as "You will be a pilot".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know :)    the absurdity just really reminded me of it

Comment: @DavidRicherby And actually it's a little more accurate than you thought.. there is a negation there after all

Comment: @d'alar'cop Sure there's a negation but "*want* to be a pilot", "*should* be a pilot" and actually "*will* be a pilot" are three different things. So, your example is actually $(\neg A\rightarrow A')\rightarrow A''$. (But it's still a great joke.)

Comment: (If loving you is wrong, I don't wanna be right), so I love you. Or, (if it's not the case that I should want to love you, then I don't want to not love you), then I want to love you. Maybe?

Comment: @sjmc that is also in Catch-22 with the prostitute regarding marriage :)

Comment: Since there seems to be some confusion among answerers: are you looking for a) a logically equivalent statement in natural language, b) a "plain English" explanation of the formula or c) a real-life example of the formula "in action"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ is always the same atomic statement, every direkt translation is going to be weird. Also, natural language does not do well with (nested) implications; we typically say "leads to" not "logically implies" in reality.

I suggest you transform the formula to

$\qquad\begin{align*}
         &(\lnot A \to A) \to A \\
  \equiv &\lnot(\lnot A \to A) \lor A \\
  \equiv &\lnot(A \lor A) \lor A \\
  \equiv &\lnot A \lor A,
\end{align*}$

which is, of course, a tautology (as you've stated):

> You will help me, or you won't [, your choice].

Coming up with more complicated sentences won't give you more (logical) meaning -- all tautologies are equivalent (in Boolean logic), after all.

Comment: Yea! "Helping" is a good verb for giving an example.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that logical equivalence preserves meaning. It does not! It preserves truth values, but that is all. If not, you would have to admit that "2 + 2 = 4" has the same meaning as "there are 24 hours in a day".

Comment: @AndrejBauer: If we only consider logics, I readily admit that the two statements you give have "the same meaning" (assuming a suitable frame of reference for both). I think you want to attach more semantics; that's outside of the scope of this question, I think.

Comment: "Meaning" and "semantics" have the same meaning :-) There is no logic without semantics.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: True; it's important to fix the semantics for the course of one discussion, though. As far as I am concerned, propositional logic has a semantics $\varphi$ that assigns every statement either "true" of "false". You propose to use other semantics to separate logically equivalent statements by meaning; that's fair, but another framework, hence another discussion.

Comment: I would say the framework you are proposing is wrong. We're talking about how to explain an argument in propositional logic to ordinary people. Most certainly we should be using the ordinary meaning of propositions, which is *not* their two-valued semantics. Ordinary people *will* object if you tell them that "2 + 2 = 4" and "there are 24 hours in a day" have the same meaning. They will also object if you try to eliminate "2 + 2 = 4" on the grounds that you only allow propositional symbols as atomic propositions.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: What good does such an explanation do if it's going to applied to mathematical logics (as I suspect is the case for our OP) but does not adhere to two-valued semantics? I don't think that it's useful to assume "ordinary people" in mathematical contexts. I note that you answer yourself by providing a different tautology, so what's your point?

Comment: My point is that the meaning of a proposition is not revealed by its two-valued semantics, and that therefore we should not claim that logically equivalent propositions have the same meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Although all tautologies can be rewritten into "true", several of them are known since classic times under specific names. After all philosophers had to learn and analyse the type of arguments they were using.

With the help of google I managed to find this proposition you refer to. It is known as "Clavius's Law" or "[Consequentia mirabilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis)".

Comment: Good find. Does not seem to answer the question, though.

Comment: @Raphael I am not sure. Using this rule as argumentation in classical philosophy might be a "real life description"?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer to your question, but an observation. The reason why you're having trouble thinking of a real-life example is that it's a theorem in classical Boolean logic, but not in a general topos or intuitionistic/constructivist logic.

Many theorems are of the form $P_1,P_2\ldots P_n \vdash Q$. Given preconditions $P_i$, you can conclude that $Q$ is true. For example, if you have a right-angled triangle and have constructed squares on all three sides, then the area of the square on the hypotenuse... you get the idea.

Moreover, many proofs are *constructive*, in that they specify a procedure for obtaining the "thing" which is the subject of the conclusion from the objects given in the premises.

A constructive proof can be thought of as a computer program which takes premises as inputs and produces a conclusion as an output. This is not just an analogy, by the way. The correspondence between programs and proofs can be made completely rigorous, but the details are beyond the scope of this answer.

The logic which specifies these kinds of proof is called *constructive logic* or *intuitionistic logic*. It is, in a sense, a subset of classical logic, because some theorems in classical logic are not theorems in constructive logic.

You can think of:

$$\vdash_{Bool} P$$

as asserting that $P$ is true, but

$$\vdash_{Con} P$$

as asserting that you can formally construct an example of $P$ being true.

An example of a statement which is true in classical logic but not in constructive logic is $\lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$. Just because you can't construct a refutation of $A$ doesn't mean you can construct a proof of $A$. Note that the converse, $A \rightarrow \lnot \lnot A$, is a theorem; a construction of $A$ is also a construction that $A$ is impossible to refute.

(An analogy that often comes up is that if it's raining, then it's not impossible that it's raining. But just because it's not impossible that it's raining doesn't mean that it *is* raining. It's a good analogy, but don't stretch it too far.)

Raphael's proof above requires double negation elimination to be a theorem, because it simplifies $\lnot A \rightarrow A$ to $A \vee A$. In intuitionistic logic, it "simplifies" to $\lnot \lnot A \vee A$, and from this you can't necessarily conclude $A$.

(Note: The word "simplifies" is in scare quotes because in intuitionistic logic, implication is just as basic a concept as conjunction or disjunction, and arguably moreso. This is beyond the scope of this discussion.)

So the reason why you had difficulty thinking up an example is that it's harder to think up non-constructive examples than constructive examples, and this theorem doesn't have a constructive proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat contrived example: a failed proof that the Halting Problem is undecidable.

**Step 1**. Suppose we could build a halt tester $H$ that acts as follows:

- $H$ takes as input a description, $\langle M\rangle$, of a TM $M$ and a word $x$.
- If $M$ halts on $x$, $H$ will halt and return "true".
- If $M$ doesn't halt on $x$, the behavior of $H(\langle M\rangle, x)$ is unspecified, except that it won't return "true".

**Step 2**. Use $H$ to construct a TM $P$ which acts as follows:

- $P$ takes a TM description $\langle M \rangle$ as input
- $P$ then runs $H$ on input $(\langle M\rangle, \langle M\rangle)$.
- If $H(\langle M\rangle, \langle M\rangle)$ returns "true", $P$ enters an infinite loop.

So, the action of $P(\langle M\rangle)$ will be as follows:

> If $M$ halts on input $\langle M\rangle$, then $P$ will not halt on input $\langle M\rangle$.

Now give $P$ its own description, $\langle P\rangle$. By the specification above, the action of $P$ will be:

> If $P$ halts on input $\langle P\rangle$, then $P$ will not halt on input $\langle P\rangle$.

Consequently, we can't have the case where $P(\langle P\rangle)$ halts, so to avoid this contradiction we must conclude that $P(\langle P\rangle)$ doesn't halt.

Now let $A=``P(\langle P\rangle)\text{ halts''}$. We've just shown that 
$$(A\rightarrow \neg A)\rightarrow\neg A$$ which is your original tautology, with the terms negated.

---

If you've gotten this far and are still interested, the correct proof that the Halting Problem is undecidable relies on using a different machine $H$ to make a different $P$ such that $P(\langle P\rangle)$ halts **if and only if** $P(\langle P\rangle)$ doesn't halt. We didn't reach this contradiction here since in step 1, $H$ wasn't built to be a decider, but rather a recognizer. In fact, the program $H$ we used here is quite possible to build: it would just simulate the action of $M$ on input $x$ and if it halts, would return "true".

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, essential uses of classical logic look weird to normal people, unless it's exactly the law of excluded middle. It's easier to explain the classically equivalent, but intuitionstically valid $(A \to \lnot A) \to \lnot A$:

> Look, if we assume $A$ holds it follows that $A$ does not hold. So how could $A$ hold?

It does indeed seem hard to come up with a real-world example.